# String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag. (Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, interpolation, gatsby

Attempting to use an alias for a long complicated Ids within my graphql query:

FAILED TO COMPILE: String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag:

```
const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    wordpress {
      menu(id: "${wordpress("mainMenu")}") {
        ...rest of query
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Docs here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/#the-longer-answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use query variable instead.

> Variables can be added to page queries (but not static queries) through the context object that is an argument of the `createPage` API. [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query)

```
// inside template file
export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery($id: String!) {
    menu(id: { eq: $id }) {
        ...rest of query
    }
  }
`
```

Then you can provide such variable as part of the page’s context in `gatsby-node.js`. For example:

```
// gatsby-node.js
const postTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/post.js`)
allWordpressPost.edges.forEach(edge => {
  createPage({
    path: `/${edge.node.slug}/`,
    component: slash(postTemplate),
    context: {
      id: edge.node.id, // 
    },
  })
})
```

Have a look at this [using-wordpress example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-wordpress) from gatsby.